# Is it necessary to insert the pronoun here? "…after which [she] looked out at the tall grasses"

Tags: pronouns

Is it necessary to insert "she" after "after which" in the following sentence?

- *Claire did not reply until she had finished cutting all the salted meat into slices, after which looked out at the tall grasses.*

I appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Comment: If you want to write formally using correct grammar, yes. If you want to speak informally and still have people understand you, probably not. Please clarify your question. (Of course, if you were speaking informally, you'd probably say "she'd" and not "she had".)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a word is missing. The clause "...looked out at the tall grasses" needs a subject, either "Claire" or "she". Consider it as separate sentences.

*Claire did not reply until she had finished cutting all the salted meat into slices.*
*After (that), Claire looked out at the tall grasses.*